# Using ColdFusion, how do I replicate a compare statement with listFind?

Tags: coldfusion, cfif

I'm setting up something to allow me to masquerade as another user in my system. But, I want to use listFind instead of a compare() method.

```
<cfif compare(session.userName, "userOne") EQ 0>
  <cfset #session.userName# = "userThree">
</cfif>
```

In the above statement, I'm  trying to conform it to a listFind, where if userOne is currently logged in, then set the session.userName to userThree. But, I'm having trouble.

What I have thus far...

```
<cfif #ListFind("userOne, UserTwo")#>
  <cfset #session.userName# = "userThree">
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to provide two independent arguments to ListFind. At the moment you are providing one string. The list is also the first arguments and string search for is the second.

```
<cfif ListFind("userOne", session.userName)>
  <cfset session.userName = "userThree">
</cfif>
```

On a side note, the hashes are only necessary for [string interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation). In other words, only when you want a variable/expression to be evaluated and inserted into a string.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Since you did an actual check on the returned value of the Compare() then I would say continue doing that method with the ListFind().  So I would adjust it to <cfif ListFind("userOne,userTwo", Session.userName) IS NOT 0> or to follow your usage of EQ then a NEQ instead of IS NOT

Comment: @Snipe656 I want to point out that ListFind returns 0 for no match or the list item number of a match, interpreted as false and true respectively since CF is starts indexing at 1. Compare on the other hand can be -1, 0 or 1, which requires some sort of check for equality or for sanity... since the function intuitively returns a truthy value when the items don't match. My point being, no reason to carry over the check just because the compare code was using it.

Comment: Compare() returns 0 if a match.  ListFind returns the placement within the list if a match otherwise 0.  The reason I said I would be specific on the check is because I am assuming since the Compare did that, then this is the methodology for checks done throughout the application.  It makes sense from a readability standpoint when debugging in the future to stick with a methodology throughout over jumping in/out.  There are of course arguments that maybe one day the language will not see value 2 to mean true anymore, which the ListFind could return in this example.